# create a temp table using union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

how to create a  temp table using a union operator

```
select top 5 Name into [#Production.Productmodel]
from          [Production].[ProductModel]
select top 5 Name into [#purchasing.shipmethod]
from          [Purchasing].[ShipMethod]
select Name into #productionprod
select  Name from [#purchasing.shipmethod]
union
select  Name from [#Production.Productmodel]
```

but i still getting an error(invalid column name)

Answer (score 4):

The reason your query fails is that you are repeating the `SELECT NAME`in the query, so remove the second one:

```
select Name 
into #productionprod
from [#purchasing.shipmethod]
union
select Name from [#Production.Productmodel]
```

You could also have used two subqueries like this:

```
select Name into #productionprod
from (
  select Name from [#purchasing.shipmethod]
  union
  select Name from [#Production.Productmodel]
) subquery
```

On a side note: if the only reason you are first selecting into `[#Production.Productmodel]` and`[#purchasing.shipmethod]`is to use those temp tables as a source from `SELECT ... INTO #productionprod` then your query could be simplified to this:

```
SELECT Name INTO #productionprod
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 Name 
    FROM  [Production].[ProductModel] ORDER BY name
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 5 Name 
    FROM  [Production].[ShipMethod] ORDER BY name
) a
```

Please note that when you use`TOP n`without`ORDER BY`the order is undefined as stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

> When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result
>   set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it
>   returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `into`.  Here is an example:

```
select Name
into #productionprod
from [#purchasing.shipmethod]
union
select Name
from [#Production.Productmodel]
```